# What type of git server on a developers machine?

Tags: git

Today we have a public repository with ssh where everyone has access through their own user accounts. This works great in-house.

However, we are often on integration trips at the customer site where we have network access, but don't have internet access. we need to share code directly between the developers on site. What's an easy and a good way to let developers pull changes directly from each other?

We use Windows on our development laptops.

Comment: you can pull/push to anyone's git repo you can access - so e.g allow each other ssh access to your laptops to permit `git pull git@dagur:repo.git` to work whilst on your integration-trip e-island.

Comment: how whould you set up ssh for this on Windows?

Comment: that's why it's not an answer, I don't use windows - I don't know. But I bet [someone using mysgit](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/msysgit) does know

Answer (score 1):

Use a shared local network drive.